# From a Linear Transformation of an integral, find specific polynomial p in P and in null(T).

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Concerning the problem below, I am unsure if I'm taking the correct steps to solving it. Also, I'm not sure if $R$ actually means $R^4$.

Let $T:\mathcal{P}_3 \rightarrow R$ be the linear transformation such that $Tp=\int_0^1p(t)dt$.

(a). Find a specific example of a polynomial, $p$, so that $p\in\mathcal{P}_1$ and $p\in$ null$(T)$.

(b). Find null$(T)$.

$$\\$$My steps:

We can say $p(t)=\alpha t^3+\beta t^2+\gamma t+\delta 1 \mid \alpha,\beta,\gamma\delta\in R$ where $\mathcal{P}_3=span\left\{p(t)\right\}$, to transform $p$ to a vector in $R$.

Thus, $Tp = \alpha\frac{1}{4}t^4+\beta\frac{1}{3}t^3+\gamma\frac{1}{2}t^2+\delta 1t$.

(a) An example of a polynomial $p$ so that $p\in \mathcal{P}_1$ would be $p(t)=\delta t$ or would it be more percise such as  $p(t)=\delta t+1$?

(b) If $R$ is referring to $R^4$ then would null$(T)$ simply be $\left\{\epsilon 1|\epsilon\in R\right\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Take $p(t)=2t-1$. Then $p\in\mathcal P_1$ and $\int_0^1p(t)\,\mathrm dt=0$.

(b) Since$$\int_0^1\alpha t^3+\beta t^2+\gamma t+\delta\,\mathrm dt=\frac\alpha 4+\frac\beta3+\frac\gamma2+\delta,$$then$$\operatorname{null}T=\left\{\alpha t^3+\beta t^2+\gamma t+\delta\in\mathcal P_3\,\middle|\,\frac\alpha 4+\frac\beta3+\frac\gamma2+\delta=0\right\}.$$